# How to check if an element exist in a td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having following html

```
<td id="td0" style="width:180px;" class="even"> 
        <strong>Bedroom</strong> <br>
        <span class="manufacturer_links"> 
            <a href="http://testsite.com/bedroom-furniture/beds.htm?manufacturer=2441">Coaster Furniture&nbsp;Beds</a>
        </span>
    <br>    
        <span class="manufacturer_links"> 
        <a href="http://testsite.com/bedroom-furniture/bed-frames-headboards.htm?manufacturer=2441">Coaster Furniture&nbsp;Bed Frames &amp; Headboards</a>
        </span>
    <br>
    <br>            
</td>
```

I do not want to display whole

`<td id="td0" style="width:180px;" class="even">` 
class and id of td will be updating dynamically.

if  `<span class="manufacturer_links">` does not exist in the td

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if it exists, then do anything you want:

```
if( $('#td0 .manufacturer_links').length == 0) { //the class we look for does not exist in td0 element
    //do anything, such as delete the td?
    $('#td0').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use selector magic:

```
$('td:not(:has(span.manufacturer_links))').addClass('collapsed');
```

Comment: I want to select <td> using id filed id="td0" , because this td is generating dynamically. what is class collapsed?

Comment: @Muk Can't you select `<td>` by class name instead? `collapsed` is the opposite of `whole`.

Comment: I have class names as <td id="td0" style="width:180px;" class="even">  and <td id="td0" style="width:180px;" class="odd">

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$("td#td0").not(":has(span.manufacturer_links)").css("display", "none");
```